# Why “filter:retweets” is not working in TweetDeck?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

`filter:retweets`, `filter:replies` Doesn’t seem to be working.

[from:1tvpmr filter:retweets](https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&q=from%3A1tvpmr%20filter%3Aretweets) show no results on Twitter. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right URI: https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3A1tvpmr%20AND%20-filter%3Aretweets&src=typd

[Source](http://thesocialchic.com/2013/04/26/how-to-master-twitter-search/).